# Allow button to be pressed once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button like this:

```
<fieldset>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Color" name="Color" required>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Bird" name="Bird" required>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
     <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Lagre</button>
</fieldset>
```

The form will be submitted only if the text fields have value. But if the user spam the "submit" button and press it 5 times, the form will be submitted 5 times. How can I disable the button after the first press? I know about `document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;`, but if the user forget to type in value in "Bird" and press the button, the user can't press it again. Any tips?

Comment: Are these fields inside of a form? Just listen for `onsubmit`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, they are inside a form: `<form id="proceed" action="insert.php" method="post">` :)

Answer (score 0):

this will clear form if user sent a valid input.
otherwise they will be able to click but event will be prevented. so it won't submit the form until it's valid. you can pop a message if you want.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit')
var colorInput = document.querySelector('input[name=Color]')
var birdInput = document.querySelector('input[name=Bird]')


btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if(colorInput.value.trim().length === 0 && birdInput.value.trim().length === 0){
        e.preventDefault()
        return
    } else {

        btn.disabled = true;
        colorInput.value = ""
        birdInput.value = ""
        btn.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Color" name="Color" required>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Bird" name="Bird" required>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Lagre</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your submit function, check if the input fields are already filled. If not then show an alert. Once this condition is satisfied, you can disable the button.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guv12f83/

```
function submitForm() {
  const color = document.getElementById('colorInput').value.trim();
  const bird = document.getElementById('birdInput').value.trim();
  if (color.length > 0 && bird.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true
    console.log('Enter your code here')
  } else {
    alert('Please fill all fields')
  }
}
```